# how can I access node.js process.env.ENV_VARIABLE in scala.js?

Tags: scala.js

How can I get system environment variables at runtime in a scala.js program running in node?

In node I use `process.env.ENV_VARIABLE` and in JVM scala `sys.env.getOrElse(...)`

I've found compile-time config libs but it is unclear how to inject deployment time settings like keys and URLs to a precompiled `_fastopt.js` single file deployment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply access `process.env.ENV_VARIABLE` through Scala.js' interoperability features.

In a dynamically typed way:

```scala
import scala.scalajs.js

val foo = js.Dynamic.global.process.env.ENV_VARIABLE.asInstanceOf[js.UndefOr[String]]
```

Or using the static types of https://github.com/scalajs-io/nodejs:

```scala
import io.scalajs.nodejs.global

val foo = global.process.env.get("ENV_VARIABLE")
```

Comment: is this meant to be working out of the box? I'm getting an error: `cannot read property env of undefined`

Comment: It should work out of the box in the default Node.js environment. But if you modify `jsEnv` or run in the browser, there will be no such thing as the `process` variable.